# Update Bootstrap modal body with pk/id for Django form

Tags: javascript, django

I have table with data provided by Django. Each row has naturally different data and different 'pk'. I'd like to use Bootstrap Modals to render form and send it back to Django, to edit the fields.
I spent hours to find and try different solutions from SO, but it still don't work for my case.
Please help as I'm out of options now.

Here is pure code I manage to produce:

**HTML:**

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updatemodal"
   title="Update"
   class="btn btn-icon btn-light btn-hover-primary btn-sm mx-3" data-url="{% url 'event:event-update' event.pk %}">link
</a>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="updatemodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Update Event</h5>
                <!--begin::Close-->
                <div class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-active-light-primary ms-2"
                     data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                     aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-2x"></span>
                </div>
                <!--end::Close-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="update-form" method="POST"
                      action="#">
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn btn btn-danger font-weight-bold ml-2">
                        Update Event
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#updatemodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var trigger = $(e.relatedTarget).data('url');
    console.log(trigger);
    document.getElementById("update-form").setAttribute("action", trigger);
});
```

Note:
I use BS 5.0.0-beta3 + JQ 3.6
As for now I get it from here:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. So you have a data table with multiple objects. And you want to just click on one and update that object in a modal, right?
This is very complicated to do, so I would recommend to just redirect to a new Page where you could just use `UpdateView`, that solves all your problems. If you want to use a more dynamic approach, maybe you should have a look into NodeJs frameworks like React.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. 
In fact I’m quite surprised that this isnt much more easy as this looks like quite natural case. I tried to find a way here and there but there is no golden solution. 
I use the approach you mentioned in other cases where more fields are posibble to be updated but here I need to update just two, so it could be small and fit modal.